# Retrieving "int" from NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, int

I am reading some json output... just some integers.  The first NSLog outputs things perfectly.  In this case there are 3 elements.  I don’t understand how to access a specific element I guess.

```
NSMutableArray *json = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data   options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"json: %@ \n",json);

int count = (int)[json objectAtIndex:0];
int count1 = (int)[json objectAtIndex:1];
int count2 = (int)[json objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"count %i %i %i\n",count,count1,count2);
```

Comment: Why cast to an int if id declares the method -intValue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that those are NSNumbers.  Try this:

```
int count = [[json objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int count1 = [[json objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
int count2 = [[json objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
NSLog(@"count %i %i %i\n",count,count1,count2);
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray` contains an object, you should not cast it to `int`, this will not work. Review your code and determine the output of `NSJSONSerialization`. If it's an integer, it's usually an instance of `NSNumber`, so try:

```
int count = [[json objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` cannot use `int`s and other non-id objects as keys or values, so the cast is not going to work. Most likely the values are of type `NSNumber`, so you need to call `intValue` on them:

```
int count = [[json objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int count1 = [[json objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
int count2 = [[json objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
```